# Large data and high dimensionality

Tags: large-data, high-dimensional

As I assume, we more often have datasets with (A) very many cases (objects) and not so many variables (properties) (= large data) than the other way around: (B) just a few cases and many more variables (= high dimensionality).

There are other conceivable cases: (C) few cases, few variables, (D) very many cases, equally many variables.

I assume, that for these different cases, different statistical methods will be applied. Is this true, and how can these be characterized?

Further, I wonder, how often each of these cases does occur in practice (proportionally, estimated) - and from which disciplines they typically stem.

Comment: Even though I think the gist of this question is interesting, it is really hard to truly answer it. I can very easily 'guestimate' all four scenarios happen equally often, which may be correct in my field, and wrong in another or in the grand total of studies and data-collections. Moreover, statistical methods aren't applied because of data-structure, but because of relevancy and applicability to the research question, i.e. reason for collecting the data in the first place. Could you clarify what it is you are after? (general discussion, polling which scenario is applicable, ..., etc.)

Comment: Would you mind to tell me what your field is? And what means "few" and "very many" in your field?

Comment: for what it's worth: biomedical research. As to 'few' and 'very many', I do not mean to be rude but 'few'='few' and 'very many'='very many'... I would not dare generalize towards these vague descriptions for all biomedical studies. Again it is the study goal which directs whether your sample size and 'dimensionality' are **relatively** small or large.

Answer (score 3):

This question may be too broad to answer. What model to use depends on the hardware software and the requirement from business. In addition, as mentioned in the comments, different fields may have different definitions on how big the data is.

- In medical study, it is very costly to get few data points. If we have thousands patient's data with different treatment, that would be considered is big enough.
- In bioinformatics, we usually have many "features" (say from DNA) but few "instances".
- In computer science, say pattern recognition on images. It is very common to have billion of instances (pictures) and millions of features (pixels in an image) for one instance.